# Open c++ ui form in QML using Menu item

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to build a QML Project in Qt Creator, and i have a ui form build in c++, now I need to show a ui form when the menu item is triggered, Is that possible in Qt using QML? .

//QML Code

```
  MenuItem { text: "OverView"
   onTriggered: contentFrame.replace("qrc:/overview.qml")
         }
```

Comment: You have to clarify your question. And you have to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of piece of code that explain nothing. What does _show ui form_ mean? You want to edit the *.ui file or you want to open the form? Usually `uic` utility have to produce *.h and *.cpp files and so you open the form class using `form.open()`. In this case you have to understand that Qt form is `Qt.Widgets` and `QML` is `QtQuick`, a completely different subsystem from the first one.

Comment: Yes i want to open form class in my qml code using menu item, can i do that in QT?

Comment: As I know the answer is NO, but you can try maybe [QWidget::createWindowContainer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer).